# Can this sentence be correct? Please explain

Tags: grammar, sentence

'That moment when you've just shaved and returned in time when you were 17. '
Well, I hope you understood what I mean.. So, can native speakers use it? Or it's incorrect?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

'That moment when you've just shaved and returned in time [to] when you were 17' is a dependent clause and needs an independent clause to complete it: Perhaps, "you will understand the weight of experience."

This would make it a complex sentence and it would certainly be understood. The dependent clause can be understood on its own but not as a complete thought

Comment: -1 Please refrain from answering off-topic/proofreading requests.

Comment: @NVZ I have worked as a proofreader and that post was not something a proofreader would address. A copyeditor might, but she would not be required to explain the reasoning behind her actions.

Comment: That's beside the point. I'm saying it's not good to answer such off-topic questions. Answering them will encourage others to ask similar questions. I hope you understand.

Comment: @NVZ Yes, of course. By the way, how did you get a minus one for your comment? Not only didn't I do it, I didn't know it could be done.

Comment: That was not a -1 for my comment. It was me writing to you that I -1'd your answer for the reason I said in the comment. :)

Comment: Thank you for the courtesy, But wait, thank yous are forbidden. I give myself another  -1.